# Adding Event Handler to DropDownList inside GridView - how to?

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, ascx

I have DropDownList inside GridView. Now I would like to add event handler for dropdownlist which would react on SelectedIndexChanged.
I'm nesting DropDownList inside GridView by using RowDataBound event for GridView.
(http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/169_DropDownList_Inside_GridView__Method_1_.aspx)
Can anybody help me, and tell me how to add event handling for dropdownlist, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the issue I've had is solved.
To handle `SelectedIndexChanged` for DropDownList nested inside GridView you have to just set `AutoPostback` property to `true` and point SelectedIndexChange event to some procedure.

The cause of issue I had was that I didn't check in Page_Load function (during binding data to GridView) following rule: `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then`. And that's all. So don't forget to do it please! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `GridView1_RowDataBound` method, add the handler when you create the drop down by calling `ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);`

Then, declare the `void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method to handle your logic. The `sender` argument will be a reference to the drop down's that was selected.

Comment: Tried to do this earlier, as you said, bud it didn't work. :(
Event SelectedIndexChanged was not raised. Any idea why?
I also tried to add event inside ascx.vb file... As well didn't work... Event was not raised.

Comment: Did you try setting the "AutoPostBack" property of the drop down to "true"?

Comment: Yes it was set to true. The postback occurs.

Comment: It seems that RowCommand is not raised as well. :( Help please!

Comment: Enough to do is to ad OnSelectedIndexChange inside ascx control.

Answer (score 0):

Two events of gridview are used for dropdownlist selected index changed.

1. `RowDataBount` event handler of grid view (for item selection).
2. `RowUpdating` event handler of grid view (for updating of selected item with grid view).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was useful.

**I had a similar scenario, where i had a list of items to be added to the stock of products.
When i chose a product, i need to display its unit (kg/litre) in the next column.**

[image]

For that, i need to find the exact row in the grid view where the product dropdown is present. So in the selected_index_changed event, i looped thru each gridview row, and matched the dropdown id.

> But the problem was the "id" of the dropdown remains same in all the rows.
>   So i added one more condition for matching the ddl's client id with
>   the sender's client id, and it worked perfectly.

So, thought of sharing my experience.

> Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Add the onRowCommand event on the grid view, add a command name to the dropdown list, set its autoPostback property to true and in the onRowCommand event check the e.CommandName (in case you have other events the grid view is throwing like paging).

Comment: I couldn't add successfully RowCommand. :( It always trows some errors while I was trying.